# How to change mysql version from 8.0 to 5.6 in docker-compose.yml of laravel 8 project?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I installed laravel 8 via sail. By default docker-compose.yml use mysql:8. But I need to change mysql version to 5.6 or 5.7.

When I run `sail up -d` and than run `docker-compose ps` I see that mysql container not running:

```
myproject_mysql_1          docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Exit 2
```

My docker-compose.yml (I changed only "`image`" property):

```
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:5.7'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
```

And I created new Dockerfile for php image and I only changed php version from 8 to 7.3 in this file.

Other containers work correctly. When I change mysql version to 8, mysql container works correctly to.

Comment: note that 5.6 is no longer supported by oracle; that means no security fixes, unless you pay a third party (percona, for one) for support.  soon this will be true of 5.7 as well.

Comment: Is there any error in [the log files](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command:

```
sail down --rmi all -v
```

Old volumes was deleted and ploblem was solved.